# How do I draw these lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I am trying to reproduce a poster I found, but I don't know exactly how to reproduce these concentric red lines inside the black circle.

[image]

I tried to use spirals but it didn't quite do the work. I could draw one by one but I am sure there is a better way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question because there are several ways this could be done.  Here's another method, using only three paths.

1. Drop a horizontal and vertical guide to give you a centre origin. Lock the guides.
2. Draw a circle centred on the origin, then fill it with purple, add a red stroke.
3. Using the Arc Tool - draw a single arc that fits to the edge of the circle, stroke red, no fill.  Then click `Object` > `Arrange` > `Send to Back`
4. Using the centre origin again, draw a black circle, no fill, thick black stroke.
5. Then group everything.

[image: Example set up]

6. Now, open the Appearance panel, and click on the **fx** button, and click `Distort & Transform` > `Transform`
7. Set the rotation angle to 45, copies to 7, enable the preview option to see it. Click OK to accept.

[image: Example of applying transform]

Comment: Very interesting, I loved this solution! It's probably the one I am going to use

Answer (score 3):

[image]

1. Draw an ellipse
2. Duplicate it (= drag horizontally holding Alt) Have the Smart Quides ON to be easily able to move only horizontally

3-4. Take the direct selection tool and delete 2 anchor points from each. Group the remaining quarters to keep them together.

5. Goto Object > Transform > Rotate, -45 degrees, Copy
6. Repeat 2 times by pressing Ctrl+D
7. This is optional (no image) Goto Object > Transform > Reflect > Vertical if you want to change the apparent rotational direction.

Comment: In step 2, you don't need smart guides if you hold Alt **and** Shift.  Shift will constrain to horizontal, vertical, or 45 degree diagonals.

Comment: @Wildcard OK, marked the comment =useful.

Comment: Also smart guides do not necceserily imply alignment guides as you can separately turn those off. (i do since they interfere with accurate drawing in certain cases)